# 2 Pagers on in View - Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, pager

I am wondering how it would be possible to have a pager at the top and the bottom of my table which I created with Views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by copying the views-view.tpl.php from the views/theme directory, into your theme. Once it is there, edit it, and copy the lines

```
<?php if ($pager): ?>
  <?php print $pager; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

from below the `views-content` section, and place another copy above.

Note that this will duplicate the pager for *all* of your views. If you only need to do this on a very specific view, you can click on the theme information section of the views edit form, and it will show you all the possible templates for a specific view.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the custom pager module on my drupal 7 website (as for now on a local host), but could not get it to display two pagers despite the correct configuration.

As a css-addict I enclosed the top-pager in a div:

```
<?php if ($pager); ?>
   <div class="top-pager"> <?php print $pager; ?> </div
<?php endif; ?>
```

I used the combined classes in a view-styles.css file that was sitting in my theme css directory

```
.view-titleview .top-pager {css code}
```

to have the pager displayed on a specific view. The class .view-titleview can be found in the source code of the specific webpage: ctrl-u in chrome or IE, or fire-bug

To show the same pager on several views, you can add the classes to the same css-code like:

```
.view-titleview1 .top-pager, view-titleview2 .top-pager {css code}
```

Remember to put a blanc space between the two classes. And don't forget to also remove the , when deleting the second combined classes.